# What is an automorphic representation of CM type ?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, rt.representation-theory

In a recent paper of BL-Gee-Geraghty: "Sato-Tate for Hilbert modular forms" (JAMS 2011), a theorem is proved for regular algebrai cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL_2(\mathbb A_F)$  with $F$ a totally real field, which is not of CM type.  I could not find any definition or reference for "CM type" in that paper. But I expect it should correspond to CM elliptic curve in the classical modular case.

My question is :

1. What is the precise definition for "an automorphic representation of CM type", both in the $GL_2$  case here and for general reductive group over number fields.

   I prefer a definition "purely" in terms of representation-theory, not of arithmetic-geometry.
2. Why is the CM case excluded in that paper ?

Any comments or references will be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: Dear unknown, The distribution law for Hecke eigenvalues is different in the CM and non-CM cases (e.g. because the Mumford--Tate groups are quite different in the two cases).  This is probably discussed in various expository articles about Sato--Tate, such as the one by Mazur.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton: Thank you ! Has the distribution law in the CM case been already known in general ?

Comment: A "pure" representation-theory definition: a $GL_2$ automorphic representation $\pi$ is of CM type if there is a quadratic idele class character $\eta$ such that $\pi \simeq \pi \otimes \eta$.

Comment: David Hansen: Thanks ! It looks like a characterization rather than  a definition. 

Comment: Dear unknown, The distribution in the CM case has been known since Hecke, and is much simpler.  (The relevant $L$-functions reduce to abelian, or Hecke, $L$-functions for the CM extension, whose analytic properties were established by Hecke.)  Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.-- in the $Gl_2$-case, $\pi$ is of CM type if it is the automorphic induction
of a Grossencharacter of a CM extension K of $F$. In terms of the Galois representation
of $Gal(\bar F/F)$ attached to $\pi$, that means that $\pi$ is not the induced representation from a character of a subgroup $Gal(\bar F/K)$ of index $2$, where $K$ is a CM extension of 
$F$.

In the general case, the notion of CM stratifies into many different notions. Read things about the Mumford-Tate groups for more about this.

2.-- because already in the $F=\mathbb{Q}$-case, the Sato-Tate conjecture excludes the CM case.